# confusion in regex pattern

Tags: regex, hadoop, mapreduce

```
private static Pattern inputPattern = Pattern.compile("(.*) (\\d*)");
```

I am a beginner to coding. I am trying to understand and learn from net. In the above line `pattern.compile()`, I couldn't understand. I read documentation on reg- ex patterns but still couldn't co-relate what it is telling in that brackets.

Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: I find http://www.regular-expressions.info/ much clearer than most docs on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the parts of this regexp:

`(.*)` = a group `()` consisting of zero or more instances `*` of *any character* `.`

= a space

`(\\d*)` = a group `()` consisting of zero or more instances `*` of any digit `\\d`

So this regexp matches "abcde 34454" and "44" and " 445" but not "abcde44".
Note that `\d` is a digit but the backslash requires escaping, hence the `\\d`

Comment: It can be very helpful to test them at a site like http://regexpal.com/, though that one does not require escaping characters so change `\\`d` to `\d`.

Answer (score 1):

The Documentation for Java's `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes should help:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

In addition, I recommend reading about Regular Expression Syntax.

To answer your question:

`.` is a regular expression element, it represents any character except a newline

`*` is a flag for an element, denoting "zero or more of the preceding element".

`\d` is a regular expression element, it represents any single integer 0-9.

A capture is represented by parenthesis.
This expression has two captures, one for the `.*` and another for the `\d*`.

There is a space between the captures which will match a single literal space.  I recommend using `\s` instead.

A few matching strings:

```
"zxcvb 12345"
"zxcvb "
" 12345"
```

Unless you are planning on retrieveing the information from the 1st and/or 2nd capture, I would change the expression to something more appropriate.

Example:    `.*\s\d*`

Comment: Thanks to all of you.